# Add excel workbook to VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, excel, dll, reference

I have a project that I created that only shows 1 form and button.  What I am trying to do is once the button is clicked, it opens a pre-built excel workbook.  The problem is, I need to add the excel file within the application bundle. For example, I give the application disc to someone else to load on another computer, and then they can run the application to open the workbook.  I know how to reference the file on my personal computer, just not how to add it "within" the project, to be, more or less, stand-alone.  The application if for inventory purposes but it needs to be opened on numerous computers...this is kinda like using VB as a front end to excel workbook. I know very little about Vb.net but willing to learn.  Requesting a walkthrough of steps. Please help!!

Comment: Awesome, now inside the userform button code, how do i get the workbook to open when the user clicks the button?

Comment: I didn't add any code to the form button yet, just not sure where to start...

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select *Add>Existing Item...*
2. Browse to the workbook, and click the *Add* button.
3. The file should now appear in the list of files below the project in the Solution Explorer. Select the file.
4. In the Properties window, change the *Copy to Output Directory* property to *Copy always*.

This should put the workbook in the some folder as the executable. This will also make a copy of the workbook and add it to you project folder. If you don't want that to happen, the use the drop-down on the right-hand side of the *Add* button (see Step 2 above), and select *Add as Link*. Then builds will use the file as it's found in its current location.

To open the workbook programmatically, do:

```
Dim filename as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & "WorkbookName.xlsx"
Process.Start(filename)
```

This example assumes that the file is named, *WorkbookName.xlsx*, you'll need to change it to match the name of your file.

Comment: inside the button code,how do I get the workbook to open when the user clicks the button? I haven't added any code yet, don't know where to start.

Comment: @JoshuaYohn I added code to open the file programmatically.