# Add excel workbook to VB .NET application

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, visual-studio, excel-2010

I have a project written in Vb .NET in which I take input from the user, open a Excel template and run a macro in it(vba) with input from main form.
I can do all of this without a problem using a path to the template but I need it to be part of the project when I publish it.
This is my path version code(excess code deleted):

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
private sub OpenExcel()
Dim objApp As Object
        Me.Hide()
        objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objApp.WorkBooks.Open("ExampleWorkBook.xlsm")
        objApp.visible = True
        objApp.Run("MacroName", Var1, Var2)
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499147/add-excel-workbook-to-vb-net-application) but it doesn't work, maybe because my templates are in a folder(which is located in same location as form1.vb etc).
My templates must be separate from other files so they are easy to find.
If anyone could provide me with a solution/modify code from other post in such a way it works I would be really thankful

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Excel 2010
Code from linked post:

```
Dim filename as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & "WorkbookName.xlsx"
Process.Start(filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution but then I have run into another problem: I would get an error saying the path is invalid, object is missing. I was sure it was a problem with path but it was related to resource properties(type:content instead of none and copy always so it is in the folder with the application).

Code for opening the excel template:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
private sub OpenExcel()
Dim objApp As Object
        Me.Hide()
        'This path is independent of where the program is installed as it refers to program itself
        Dim ResourcePath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath &
            System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & "Templates\Rate_Reach_ATT finished.xlsm"
        objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objApp.WorkBooks.Open(ResourcePath)
        objApp.visible = True
        objApp.Run("MacroName", Var1, Var2)
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

As for resource itself:
Project>Add existing item>browse>add
Then find the item in solution explorer, open it's properties and change:
Type:Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

The issue has been fixed so I close this thread